# Why am I not able to find the length of those array in cpp

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, iterator, sizeof

I am trying to find the length of this array and am wanting to find its length so I can use it in a for loop.

```
// importing needed libraries
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <set>

// preventing need of std::cout, std::endl etc
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int nums[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

    int size;
    size = nums.size();

    cout << size;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    {
        cout << nums[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The line using the .size() method is the one which is causing issues

The issue:-

```
error: member reference base type 'int [6]' is not a structure or union
```

From what I understand, my use of the .size() should be correct, but its clear not.

Comment: `.size()` is a method on `std::vector` or `std::array`. Plain C++ arrays *do not support method calls*.

Comment: Where did your understanding come from? You likely misunderstood something in your C++ textbook, can you cite a brief excerpt from your textbook that led you to believe this?

Comment: I just searched it on google

Answer (score 3):

Arrays do not have methods. So this code snippet is incorrect.

```
int size;
size = nums.size();
```

If your compiler supports C++ 17 then you can include the header

```
#include <iterator>
```

and then write

```
size_t size = std::size( nums );
```

Or you could even write yourself such a function like for example

```
template <size_t N>
size_t array_size( const int ( &a )[N] )
{
    return N;
}
```

and in main write

```
size_t size = array_size( nums );
```

Another approach is to include the header

```
#include <type_traits>
```

and write

```
size_t size = std::extent<decltype( nums )>::value;
```

Or you can just write

```
size_t size = sizeof( nums ) / sizeof( *nums );
```

Pay attention to that to output the array you need not to know its size. You could write

```
for ( const auto &item : nums ) 
{
    cout << item << endl;
}
```

The array also can be outputted using iterators like

```
#include <iterator>

//...

for ( auto first = std::begin( nums ); first != std::end( nums ); ++first )
{
    cout << *first << endl;
}
```

Using iterators you can also get the number of elements in the array like

```
auto size = std::distance( std::begin( nums ), std::end( nums ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Also I want to offer another way:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void solve()
{
    int numbers[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    int numbersSize=0;
    for(int& item : numbers)
    {
        cout<<item<<", ";
        ++numbersSize;
    }
    cout<<endl<<"numbersSize <- "<<numbersSize<<endl;
    return;
}
int main()
{
    solve();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the result:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
numbersSize <- 6
```

So, the sense of the parameter `numbersSize` is the size of the parameter `numbers`.

Comment: Why calculate at *runtime* what the compiler can solve immediately during *compilation*? Apart from, you cannot output *before* iterating over the loop – which seems to be desired, though.